# Func<SocketMessage, Task> does not take 2 arguments, yet documentation says otherwise?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm using Discord.Net 1.0.2v Because the majority of tutorials and available documentation are from 1.0.2. Essentially I'm attempting to get a message, Download it, delete it using discord.net. It appears that I've done everything right, I've stated _client as a DiscordSocketClient, I've set all things as it should be, I've attempted to make it a function rather than its async, but it needs to be so I can do it on command. I've also tried building it from the ground up, but there were more errors than i could count with that, so here's my code.

```
    private DiscordSocketClient _client;
    [Command("NBDelete")]
    [RequireBotPermission(Discord.GuildPermission.ManageMessages)]
    [RequireUserPermission(Discord.GuildPermission.ManageMessages)]
    public async Task DeleteNonBotMessages()
    {

        _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
        // error starts here
        _client.MessageReceived += async (s, e) =>
        {
            var channel = e.Server.FindChannels("general", ChannelType.Text).FirstOrDefault();
            var user = _client.CurrentUser;
            spamold = spamnew;
            Message[] messagesToObtain;
            messagesToObtain = await e.Channel.DownloadMessages(1);
            spamnew = string.Format(messagesToObtain);
            if (spamnew == spamold)
            {
                Message[] messagesToDelete;
                messagesToDelete = await e.Channel.DownloadMessages(2);
                await e.Channel.DeleteMessages(messagesToDelete);
            };

        };
    }
```

I expect the program to be able to pull in messages, download them then allow me to delete them.
The full error is "`Delegate'Func<SocketMessage, Task>`' does not take 2 arguments"

Comment: When you have `Func<T, TResult>` then one is an argument and the other is the return.

Comment: `Func<SocketMessage, Task>` only takes one argument, and you are not using the `s` argument anywhere. Try removing that.

Comment: You are using methods that only exist in 0.9, which is completely incompatible with 1.0 and above. Furthermore, 2.0 is the latest version that you should be using.

Comment: Additionally, the latest Discord.Net documentation is on discord.foxbot.me/latest or docs.stillu.cc - wherever you obtained your documentation or snippet from is unfortunately very out of date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full declaration of `Func<T, TResult>` is

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T,out TResult>(T arg);
```

which is a delegate (function that can be assigned to a variable) that has the parameter `T` and the return value `TResult`.

Hence `Func<T, TResult>` has two **type parameters**, but the function has **one argument** and a return value. An object of type `Func<SocketMessage, Task>` is a delegate that takes a `SocketMessage` and returns a `Task`. Hence the signature of your lambda method would be the following

```
_client.MessageReceived += async (socketMessage) =>
{
    // ... do your stuff here
};
```

**Please note** that `SocketMessage` does not seem to have a property `Server`. Something withing your lambda is not correct, beyond the wrong signature.